# How to integrate PHP job in airflow?

Tags: php, docker, airflow, etl

Can we run PHP Job with Airflow ? i try many methods and search for reference, but most of them make connection with PostgreSQL and easy to connect by setting it in airflow connection || My PHP Job have data from 2 different Docker Port database || I try to run the job in docker terminal but the error notification is "could not find driver"

PHP, database ( MySQL & clickhouse) on Docker :
[image: DOCKER CONTAINER]

Airflow on Docker :
[image]